# Is is posible to self register as a community user in the dev org?

Tags: community, napili

I need to activate self registration on the Napili template. I have activated `Allow external users to self-register` check box and `Assign registering users to a profile`. But once external user going to self register with the portal I'm getting this error:

> The site is not enabled for registration.

I'm using a dev org.

Answer (score 3):

The community creates a site by default .Whenever you spin a new community a force.com site is automatically created by SFDC and linked in sandbox .

In developer org sometimes you can create a site and it will automatically link to the community .

[image]

[image]

The above screenshot shows for every community I have a site created and it has self registeration page attached in site settings .

Also if you are using registration page that comes with sites in SFDC then associate the proper profiles and roles in the controller apex provided by salesforce

[image]